# Reorder all the columns in a data table based on Other files rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have 1 `data.table(dt1)` that has some ids sorted with my criteria.

```
1. id10
2. id7757
3. id75340
4. id999
5. id5498
```

and a 2nd `data.table(dt2)` with the id's of the first `data.table` as column names.

```
SOURCE    id7757    id8948    id5498    id999     id10    id75340
source1   32        87        643       8676      34      10
source2   65        32        876       9457      8       777
source3   64        666       99        222       66      222
```

How can I short the columns of the 2nd `data.table` based on the order of the 1st `data.table`? Meaning that the id on the 1st position should be 1st column, 2nd position~2nd column etc...

The output file should be as follows:

```
SOURCE    id10    id7757    id75340    id999    id5498
source1   34      32        10         8676     643
source2   8       65        777        9476     32
source3   66      64        222        222      666
```

How can this be done in R?

Comment: `dplyr::select(dt2, dt1$ID)`?

Comment: @Nathan Day `Error: Position must be between 0 and n`

Comment: You want to sort the column names by keep the columns themselves at the same order? Are you sure it wise?

Comment: @David Arenburg I dont think in the example are in the same order. I was careful to match the exact values in the 2 examples and add "dummy" values in the 31231 column since it wasnt in the first example

Comment: Either-way, you could do `setcolorder(DT2, c(1, (match(DT1[, ID], as.integer(names(DT2)[-1])) + 1)))`. This will modify `DT2` (your second `data.table`) in place. Also, having column names as integers is a bad practice in R as they are really hard to work with and they only look like integers while they are actually characters.

Comment: @David Arenburg I changed the original problem, taking your advice about numeric ids under consideration

Comment: Did you try the code in the comment? I think just `setcolorder(DT2, c(1, (match(DT1[, ID], names(DT2)[-1]) + 1)))` should do

Comment: `dplyr::select(dt2, as.character(d1$ID))` should work too, albeit not a `data.table` solution like David's

Comment: @Nathan Day `Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.`

Comment: yea you're right, i'll get back in a sec

Comment: @David Arenburg can you tweak your code a little bit so in case the `input` file has more columns than the `sorted` files rows, then the result `data.table` is a `data.frame` with the rows of the `sorted` file as columns

Comment: @Mixalis Don't understand you, sorry.

Comment: @DavidArenburg read the question again. I rephrased it so I think it better approaches my problem now

Comment: Would that work `DT2[, DT1$ID, with = FALSE]`? If you just have `data.frame`s (not `data.table`s) then just `DT2[DT1$ID]` should do

Comment: `Error in `[.data.frame`(dt2, , sorted.file$ID, with = F) : 
  unused argument (with = F)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg it didnt work both times :/

Comment: So you don't have a `data.table` there. You have a `data.frame`. What does `DT2[DT1$ID]` gives you?

Comment: I have `data.table`. I just converted to `data.frame` to test your solution. It returns scrambled results.

Comment: `DT2[, DT1$ID, with = FALSE]` is for a `data.table`, not for a `data.frame`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127819/discussion-between-mixalis-and-david-arenburg).

Answer (score 1):

it's actually very straight forward to do this. Turns out my dataset was faulty.

So **first** sanitize your datasets people!

the solution was the following:

```
all.sorted <- read.table("sorted.txt", header=T, sep=' ', na.strings="n/a")

sorted.ids <- unlist(all.sorted$ID)
sorted.ids.sanitized <- make.names(sorted.ids)

sorted.variants <- sorted.ids.sanitized # this step was just to check if all is good and keep a copy of the original
sorted.variants <- as.character(sorted.variants)

new.order <- dt2[, sorted.variants]
```

Answer (score 0):

a base/dplyr approach:

```
new_order <- sapply(dt1$V2, grep, colnames(dt2)) %>% unlist()

select(dt2, SOURCE, new_order)

SOURCE id10 id7757 id75340 id999 id5498
1: source1   34     32      10  8676    643
2: source2    8     65     777  9457    876
3: source3   66     64     222   222     99
```

Comment: How would you do the same process if instead of `df1$ID` you would like to get the id that's on each row? Because now, the ids are sorted `id1<id2<id3` what if you have mixed ids?

Comment: are you saying an unsorted `df1$ID`, would you want to post a question with specific example and ideal output?